# Cordova camera view

Tags: cordova, camera

Is it possible to get camera view in my half of phone screen by using cordova(phonegap) orginal camera plugin? If not, how could I done it? please help, very important!

Answer (score 0):

With the default [cordova-camera-plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/) you cannot do that because at least on Android it launches another activity which is a separate app to capture the photos, it can be seen because when you add the plugin your app doesn't ask for camera permissions.

I think you should try to make your own Cordova plugin, with the native features of camera access and then it might be useful [Project Ace](http://microsoft.github.io/ace/) from Microsoft which tries to merge webviews with native apps.

Hope it helps